# Решено C# как использовать переменную Type в конструкторе дженерик класса

Tags: c#, generics, рефлексия

Пытался достать конструктор через reflection, но при указании класса Requester в typeof он запрашивает типы

Можно ли сделать как-то так?

```
var f = able.FType;
var t = able.TType;               
using (var requster = new Requester<t,f>("host"))
{

}
```

UPD

Решил эту проблему таким образом

```
var genType =typeof(Requester<string, string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
genType.MakeGenericType(t, f).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[] { "host" });
```

Но не могу привести object возвращаемый Invoke`ом к Requester

UPD 2

Решено

```
var f = able.FType;
var t = able.TType;
var genType =typeof(Requester<string,string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
var requester = genType.MakeGenericType(t, f).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string)}).Invoke(new object[] { "https://localhost:5001" });
var result = requester.GetType().GetMethod("Select",ype.EmptyTypes).Invoke(requester, null);
DataTable dt = (DataTable)typeof(DataTableParser).GetMethod("Parse").MakeGenericMethod(result.GetType().GetElementType()).Invoke(null,new object[] { result });
```

Comment: Так как вы написали нельзя, только через рефлексию

Comment: Вместо `typeof(Requester<string,string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()` можно сразу написать `typeof(Requester<,>)`